# Alternative to Wilson Score when I only have the number of ratings and the average rating?

Tags: statistics

I'm getting a list of items from an external API and each item has a number of ratings and an average rating out of 5.

What is the best way to rank them? Is it statistically sound to just convert an item with 1000 ratings and a 4/5 average to an item with 800 upvotes and 200 downvotes and use Wilson Score? If not, are there any alternatives?

Comment: This depends very much on what precisely you are trying to do with that data, and what the scale and meaning of the original data, API-provided data, and required data is. There's no general answer that solves all cases.

Comment: Might be a  better fits on crossvalidate.stackexcange.com